# Swapping data values in C#

Tags: c#

I have textbox1 and textbox2

textbox1 is assigned a value which is  5 And textbox2 is assigned a value which is 10,

I have one button below. Can someone help me with code where by when I click the button the first time ,the assigned values 5 &10 will appear  in there corresponding text boxes then when I click the second time the values just swap.whereby the value in textbox1 will now be in textbox2 and vice versa. Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your current code as a [mcve]?

Comment: @ForeverZer0 the rules of the site dictate that you must include a [MCVE] for questions asking "why isnt this code working".  Instead of us spending time guessing what the OP has and wasting time trying to back and forth, the OP should take the time to ask a complete question, where there is no ambiguity in what they need.  Giving us (the community) _all the information we need_ to solve the problem

Comment: @maccettura - The OP doesn't seem to have code that's isn't working. He looks like he's after a code writing service.

Comment: @Enigmativity true.  The [MCVE] rule also helps "filter" out those sort of questions, if they cant demonstrate that they've attempted the work then it will be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle two cases ... The first where there are no values, the second where the values need swapping...

```
private void button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox1.text=="")
    {
        textbox1.Text = "5";
        textbox2.Text = "10";
    }
    else
    {
          string temp = textbox1.Text;
          textbox1.Text = textbox2.Text;
          textbox2.Text = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP said `textbox1 is assigned a value which is 5 And textbox2 is assigned a value which is 10`, textboxes already have the values of 5 and 10

Comment: They did, and then they said the opposite.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 - `textbox1.text=""` isn't working code.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the used a single `=` rather than a double `==` for comparision! Please see my edit.

Answer (score 5):

Keep the value of one `TextBox` on a local variable:

```cs
private void button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string temporaryText = textbox1.Text;
    textbox1.Text = textbox2.Text;
    textbox2.Text = temporaryText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Ivan García Topete 